# Insert date into array

Tags: javascript

I have inserted random date into a textbox let it be 12/2/2009 now I want only 2 in this how to do it with javascript how do I need array or any other method.

Please give me an appropriate example

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
var mydate = $("textboxId").val();
var dateArr = mydate.split("/");

var date = dateArr[0];
var month = dateArr[1];
var year = dateArr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get month from 'dd/m/yyyy' formatted date by reversing the date

`new Date("12/2/2009".split("/").reverse().join("/")).getMonth()`

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/jaZZM/)